# Redcloth parsing urls with underscore results in emphasis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redcloth

We use redcloth to parse text given by users in our application.  However, there was a bug in the parser as shown below

```
>> RedCloth.new('http://www.example.com/?_test_param_=test', [:no_span_caps]).to_html
=> <p>http://www.example.com/?<em>test_param</em>=test</p>"
```

And the question is how do i make RedCloth parse the url so that the result would be `<p>http://www.example.com/?_test_param_=test</p>` (no em tags) since it is part of the url?

Comment: After trying with `==` and a few other ways, I have to say Textile is hard to work with. Not sure if this is Textile's fault or RedCloth implementation's fault. I guess if in doubt, fire a issue~

Comment: @xlembouras updated the question to make it **clear** what i'm asking.

Comment: @lulalala thanks. I'll do that.

Comment: looks like there's already a ticket for this http://jgarber.lighthouseapp.com/projects/13054/tickets/239-problem-when-using-an-underscore-to-emphasize-and-linking-an-url-with-an-underscore

Comment: Though that issue is not moved to the new github repo. He might have forgotten about it already.

Comment: hmm the issues is disabled in the github repo so i think he really uses lighthouse to keep track of these issues